# How to derive from/extend a recursive class

Tags: c++, inheritance, recursion, derived-class

I have a recursive class, a kind of tree, that has instances of itself as member variables.  For example:

```
template<class T>
class Tree {
public: 
  /* Constructors, etc. */
protected:
  T m_value;
  Tree<T> *leftChild;
  Tree<T> *rightChild;
};
```

If I want to add a method that prints all the values using an in-order traversal, I could do this:

```
template <class T>
void Tree<T>::printInOrder()
{
   leftChild->printInOrder();
   std::cout << m_value << std::endl;
   rightChild->printInOrder();
}
```

But what if, for various reasons, I couldn't or didn't want to change Tree's implementation?  If the class wasn't recursive, i.e. didn't contain instances of itself, I could just derive from Tree and implement a new method in the derived class.  But this approach doesn't work for Tree.

```
template <class T>
class DerivedClass : public Tree<T> {
public:
  void printInOrder();
}

template <class T>
void DerivedClass<T>::
printInOrder()
{
   this->leftChild->printInOrder();
   std::cout << this->m_value << std::endl;
   this->rightChild->printInOrder();
}
```

leftChild and rightChild are instances of Tree and thus don't have a printInOrder() method.

Can anyone suggest a way to do this in a modular way without changing Tree's implementation.  It's ok to change how it is implemented in general, as long as you don't have to change it whenever you want to extend/derive from the class.  I can see a possible way to do it by making the template class T have methods to do the things I want, but that just seems ugly.  There must be a better way.

I'm perfectly happy for someone to point out how I've overlooked something obvious.  It certainly feels like I have.

**Edit:** The point is not how to implement printInOrder().  That was just an example.  The point is how to derive a class so that the children are also the derived class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Template on the node type.

```
template<typename T, typename NodeType = void> class Tree {
    NodeType node;
    T m_data;
};
template<typename T> class Tree<void> {
    struct Node {
        Tree<T, void>* left;
        Tree<T, void>* right;
    };
    Node node;
    T m_data;
};
template<typename T> struct DerivedNode {
     DerivedTree<T>* left;
     DerivedTree<T>* right;
};
template<typename T> class DerivedTree : public Tree<T, DerivedNode<T>> {
     // now left and right are of type DerivedTree<T>*.
};
```

This works based on two invariants- that `Tree<T, NodeT>` offers the same interface for all `NodeT`, and that `DerivedTree<T>` inherits from `Tree<T, ...>`.

Edit: Damn, that took a lot of effort to prevent recursive instantiation of `Tree<T, NodeType>`.

Comment: Yes, this is the insight I was missing.  The children need to be templated, too, so that they can also be DerivedClass<T>.  I will select this as the answer after I try it out.

Answer (score 0):

Make `printInOrder` a `virtual` function and make it available in `Tree`.

This means tree chilren can be arbitrary descendents of `Tree` and calling `printInOrder` on them will always invoke the overriden implementation, if they provide any.

The major downside is that all methods need to be declared in `Tree`.

Comment: The trouble is that as long as leftChild and rightChild are of type Tree<T>, they will never implement printInOrder().

Answer (score 0):

You can simply write a member function that takes the instance to print:

```
template <class T>
void DerivedClass::printInOrderHelper(const Tree<T>& tree)
{
    printInOrderHelper(tree->leftChild);
    std::cout << tree->m_value << std::endl;
    printInOrderHelper(tree->rightChild);
}
```

Use this in a zero-parameter overload:

```
template <class T>
void DerivedClass::printInOrder()
{
    printInOrderHelper(*this);
}
```

Comment: I don't think this works.  tree->leftChild and tree->rightChild still aren't of type DerivedClass<T>, so they don't have a printInOrder() member.

Comment: Er yes, you are right, thanks.  I forgot to adapt those lines after copying your original code.

Answer (score 0):

If you want non-intrusive printing, just specify a plain template function for it:

```
template <typename T>
void TreePrinter(const Tree<T>& tree)
{
    TreePrinter(tree.leftChild);
    std::cout << tree.m_value << std::endl;
    TreePrinter(tree.rightChild);
}
```

You obviously need a TreePrinter as a friend though:

```
template<class T>
class Tree {
public: 
  /* Constructors, etc. */
protected:
  T m_value;
  Tree<T> *leftChild;
  Tree<T> *rightChild;

  friend template <typename U>
  TreePrinter(const Tree<U>&);
};
```

Alternatively if you don't to have it as a friend, provide accessors to get the value as well as the left and right nodes of the tree.

Comment: A friend might work for this specific instance, but as you mentioned, it requres me to modify Tree<T> to declare the friend.  I want to avoid changing Tree.  I don't mind changing how it is implemented overall, of course.  I can't solve the problem without making some kind of change, but I don't want to have to make a change for every new method or other extension I later need.

Comment: You wouldn't have to; you only need to make it a friend once. Additionally if you have accessor functions such as `getValue()`, `getLeftChild()` etc. it doesn't even have to be a friend, in which case you can even make those functions virtual and it'll work properly in case of you inherit from tree.

Answer (score 0):

Is it acceptable for you?

```
template <class T>void DerivedClass<T>::printInOrder()
{   
    ((DerivedClass<T>*)leftChild)->printInOrder();   
    std::cout << this->m_value << std::endl;   
    ((DerivedClass<T>*)rightChild)->printInOrder();
}
```

Comment: That is only legal if `leftChild` and `rightChild` were actually allocated as `DerivedClass<T>`s. If they weren't, then it isn't legal to pretend that they were with a cast. Now, it might _function_ just fine, but it certainly isn't legal according to the standard.

Comment: The way my code works, leftChild and rightChild would not be allocated as DerivedClass<T>, so the cast will not work in any event.

Comment: I believe it doesn't matter if childs are allocated as Tree or DerivedClass type. You are calling a function, passing valid this value to it and accessing `m_value` which would be always available. The function `printfInOrder`, after the cast would be mapped by compiler to call it. What if `printfIfOrder` is taking a pointer (i.e. this pointer) - the location in memory for `printIfOrder` doesn't change.