# How to derive from a base tree class

Tags: c++, tree, derived-class

I have a tree class that includes data members and member functions that operate on the data of children:

```
class Tree {
    // variables, member functions here
    Tree *parent;
    std::vector<Tree*> children;
public:
    Tree(Tree* parent, int par0 /*, other constructor parameters*/) {
        //....
        this->parent = parent;
        for (int n = 0; n < par0; n++)
            children.push_back(new Tree(this, /*other arguments*/));
        //...
    }
    void method() {
        for (auto node: children)
            node->method();
        if (children.size() == 0) {
            // Code for leaf nodes
        } else {
            // Code for internal nodes
        }
    }
};
```

The Tree constructor creates the tree structure, allocating and initializing every node according to the arguments.

I would like to add new data and functions to the class, resulting in the new class `ExtTree`, which has access to all data and functions of `Tree`, and shares as much code with it as possible.  However, in `ExtTree` both the parents and the children should be `(ExtTree*)` rather than `(Tree*)`.  How can I reorganize this code so that ExtTree would just add its own new data, and fall back on Tree for the old methods?

A related question was asked 4 years ago [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6416862/how-to-derive-from-extend-a-recursive-class), but I could not work out the solution based on the answers in that; in particular, how ExtTree would call the base constructor, or how it can access `Tree::method()`.

Answer (score 3):

You will get the best, most type-safe result by converting the whole thing to a template.

It is possible to come up with a non-template based solution, but I don't think it's going to be optimal. I am suggesting a template-based solution but, if for whatever reason, a template is not going to cut it, you might get acceptable results with the following approach:

A) Define a virtual method: `ExtTree *get_extree()`. `Tree::get_extree()` either returns `nullptr` or throws an exception (up to you, whichever works best for your application). `ExtTree::get_extree()` returns `this`.

B) Define another virtual method called `create_node()`. `Tree::create_node()` executes `new Tree( /* forwarded parameters */)`, and `ExtTree::create_node()` executes `new ExtTree( /* forwarded parameters */)`.

C) Replace all of your existing `new Tree` calls with a call to `create_node()`, instead.

D) And any other common code laying reason that needs to work with both `Tree`s and `ExtTree`s will use `get_extree()` to figure out what it's working with.

This will, more or less, get you where you want to go, mostly. A) is little different from, conceptually, just using a `dynamic_cast`(), and there's nothing wrong with using a `dynamic_cast` in lieu of `get_extree`(). But sometimes you can come across someone having an allergy to `dynamic_cast`, and this would be one way to avoid it.

I don't think there's really a perfect, 100% clean, non-template based solution here. It might be possible to get a 100% type-safe solution here by creating a much larger pile of virtual methods, and implementing pretty much everything as a virtual method.

But, I think it's going to be a lot of work. This is really what templates are for. Use them.

Comment: Thanks!  Templates would be fine, but I'm stumped how to declare them in this case.  Could you please elaborate?  I was trying template<class T> class Tree { /*...*/ std::vector<T*> children; /*...*/ }; but I could not derive a proper ExtTree from that.  What do I miss?  If my templated Tree definition works, how would you derive ExtTree?

Comment: That's the point. You do not need ExtTree at all, with templates. First of all, you'd pick some other name for the template, like "template<class T> class TreeContainer". The either Tree ot ExtTree would be a particular instance of the template. "typedef TreeContainer<TreeInfo> Tree;" and "typedef TreeContainer<ExtTreeInfo> ExtTree;".

Comment: Thanks, but this way I won't be able to extend the tree structure (TreeContainer) itself with new member functions, when I instantiate with ExtTreeInfo.  I can only add functions to ExtTreeInfo itself, but those functions won't be able to operate on the whole tree.  My original idea was to have TreeContainer have a basic set of functions when it is instantiated with TreeInfo, but provide it with an extended set of functions for ExtTreeInfo.  Is that possible in C++?

Comment: The template function does nothing but implement and support the tree operations. It's completely up to you to either subclass the template itself, or have ExtTreeInfo subclass TreeInfo.